# My skinned model gets smaller and deform badly, when I rotate its bone in Z-axis

Tags: armature

I made a model and skinned it to an armature. But when I try to deform it with a bone rotation, model doesn't just rotate, also it gets smaller.

First I thought that its because of the armature, but when I put another model, this problem doesn't occur.

Here's the .blend file: http://pasteall.org/blend/26762

Try to rotate bone "joint5" in Z-axis.

**Before rotation**

[1 http://imgim.com/2755incix2686812.jpg](http://imgim.com/2755incix2686812.jpg)

**After rotation**

[2 http://imgim.com/8460incih5544599.jpg](http://imgim.com/8460incih5544599.jpg)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Before rotated: http://imgim.com/2755incix2686812.jpg
Rotated on Z-axis (180 degrees): http://imgim.com/8460incih5544599.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't [weight painted](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Vertex_Groups/Weight_Paint) your model

From the Wiki
[Weight Paint in a nutshell](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Vertex_Groups/Weight_Paint)

Weight Painted Vertex Group

> - You enter Weight Paint mode from the Mode Menu <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>). The selected Mesh Object is displayed
>     slightly shaded with a rainbow color spectrum.
> - The color visualizes the weights associated to each vertex in the active Vertex Group. Blue means unweighted; Red means fully weighted.

[image]

Comment: I did a vertex paint but it still gets smaller. But not like before. But it still deforms badly.

Comment: Sorry, I mean weight painting. OK, I did a weight paint, "root" bone also had a weight paint of that model, so I painted it to blue, and now it works. Thanks... (I was just painted the "joint5" but, i noticed I should paint the root bone to blue)

Comment: I'n happy that I could help.